# JQuery Ajax Call causing 403.14 error in IE works fine in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following jquery/ajax function:

```
function JQueryAJAX(AjxURL, divID) {
$('.modal').show();
$.ajax({   
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    url: AjxURL,     
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) { 
        windows.location.reload();
        $('.modal').hide();
    },
    error: function(){
        // Handle your error here
    }
});}
```

My call is the following:

```
<a href="" onclick="JQueryAJAX('/ValidateEvtTeamRosters.ajx?rgs_ID=1,2,3,4', 'callback-data');">
```

In Firefox, I am not having any issues and the page reloads and the ajax works, when running in IE, since there is nothing in the href, it is simply throwing me to a 403 page error.  I cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong.  I am very new to jquery and ajax and basically attempting to hack things together.

Comment: FYI, there's no point in calling `.hide()` after `window.location.reload()`, since reloading the page stops all scripts. Also, it's `window.location`, not `windows.location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of clicking by returning `false` from the `onclick`:

```
<a href="" onclick="JQueryAJAX('/ValidateEvtTeamRosters.ajx?rgs_ID=1,2,3,4', 'callback-data'); return false;">
```

You could also use `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void 0;"` so there's no URL for it to open.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added the return false after I call the jQueryAJAX function, but in IE it still redirects to the 403...Only on IE.  All other browsers play nicely.  Ugh...I am sure it is something silly...Also, I tried a # and also the js:void, but these ended up breaking all browsers.  The page never comes back with a success when adding this.

Comment: Are there any messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: I missed your note...window.location...This is what caused the issue in IE.  Thanks again and sorry I missed that note earlier!